# How can I make EKS kick working with CircleCI?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, circleci

I can push images to ECR but I am not even close sure what I should do next (what should be the flow) to make my images run on Kubernetes on EKS

```
jobs:
  create-deployment:
    executor: aws-eks/python3
    parameters:
      cluster-name:
        description: |
          Name of the EKS cluster
        type: string
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-eks/update-kubeconfig-with-authenticator:
          cluster-name: << parameters.cluster-name >>
          install-kubectl: true
      - kubernetes/create-or-update-resource:
          get-rollout-status: true
          resource-file-path: tests/nginx-deployment/deployment.yaml
          # resource-file-path: configs/k8s/prod-deployment.yaml
          resource-name: deployment/prod-deployment
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.15.0
  aws-eks: circleci/aws-eks@1.1.0
  kubernetes: circleci/kubernetes@0.4.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  deployment:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
            repo: bwtc-backend
            tag: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}-v0.1.${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
            dockerfile: configs/Docker/Dockerfile.prod
            path: .
            filters:
              branches:
                ignore:
                  - master
      - aws-eks/create-cluster:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
          requires:
            - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image
      - create-deployment:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
          requires:
            - aws-eks/create-cluster
      - aws-eks/update-container-image:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
          container-image-updates: 'nginx=nginx:1.9.1'
          post-steps:
            - kubernetes/delete-resource:
                resource-names: nginx-deployment
                resource-types: deployment
                wait: true
          record: true
          requires:
            - create-deployment
          resource-name: deployment/nginx-deployment
      - aws-eks/delete-cluster:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
          requires:
            - aws-eks/update-container-image
```

That's what I've got in my config for now.

The problem I am facing at the moment is:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Exited with code exit status 2
CircleCI received exit code 2
```

I am using a snippet from CircleCI Documentation, so I guess it should work.
I passed in all the params as I can see but I can't get what I've missed here.

I need your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The last update has a bug. It is failing due to an incorrect URL. The issue is still open, see [here](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-eks-orb/issues/42). The correct url should be

> https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_$(uname -s)_amd64.tar.gz

unlike the current

> "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/download/latest_release/eksctl_$(uname -s)_amd64.tar.gz"

While you wait for it to be approved, use the following to install eksctl first.

```
 - run:
      name: Install the eksctl tool
      command: |
        if which eksctl > /dev/null; then
          echo "eksctl is already installed"
          exit 0
        fi
        mkdir -p eksctl_download
        curl --silent --location --retry 5 "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_$(uname -s)_amd64.tar.gz" \
          | tar xz -C eksctl_download
        chmod +x eksctl_download/eksctl
        SUDO=""
        if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ] && which sudo > /dev/null ; then
          SUDO="sudo"
        fi
        $SUDO mv eksctl_download/eksctl /usr/local/bin/
        rmdir eksctl_download
```

and then run the job

```
- aws-eks/create-cluster:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
```

That should solve the issue.
An example

```
 # Creation of Cluster        
  create-cluster:
    executor: aws-eks/python3
    parameters:
      cluster-name:
        description: |
          Name of the EKS cluster
        type: string
        
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Install the eksctl tool
          command: |
            if which eksctl > /dev/null; then
              echo "eksctl is already installed"
              exit 0
            fi
            mkdir -p eksctl_download
            curl --silent --location --retry 5 "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/latest/download/eksctl_$(uname -s)_amd64.tar.gz" \
              | tar xz -C eksctl_download
            chmod +x eksctl_download/eksctl
            SUDO=""
            if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ] && which sudo > /dev/null ; then
              SUDO="sudo"
            fi
            $SUDO mv eksctl_download/eksctl /usr/local/bin/
            rmdir eksctl_download
      
      - aws-eks/create-cluster:
          cluster-name: eks-demo-deployment
```